# Any ideas on how to recreate this part of the electric fan?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to make an electric fan (learning on blender) but I have no idea or whatsoever on how to recreate it. Here's the image below (the red outlined parts are the ones I wanted to recreate):

[image]

To make it easier here is a file with the original reference image attached to it (don't know how to paste blender files here):
[image]

A solution I once tried was to select 2 faces from the 4 locations i.e. North, South, East, and West. But the alignment of the vertices does not match one another and even if I align it the mesh itself would look weird and I wouldn't want that.

Anything is helpful, thanks!

Comment: use this to share blend-file https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You need to run File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender before uploading the file otherwise the reference image won't be included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can begin with a circle with a number of vertices that is multiple of 3 (here 18 vertex circle), keep only 1/6 of this circle, mirror it:

[image]

Array it with an object offset that is rotated 120° on Z:

[image]

Cut a hole and work its shape, change the topology:

[image]

Extrude up, make sure that there is no inner faces:

[image]

Hide the bottom faces and round the top with the *Proportional Editing* on:

[image]

Unhide the bottom, create some bevels:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused on how to keep only 1/6 of the circle and I'm also wondering how did you do the loop cuts on the 1/6 circle, can you explain it to to me much more clearer?

Comment: I create the circle and create some loopcuts, then cut off the 5/6 with the lasso tool for example

Comment: That worked, but did you use knife cut to create new vertices on 1/6 circle? I'm just wondering since that worked.

Comment: sure, in order to change the topology, I've used the knife  ;)

Answer (score 4):

start with a cube, delete parts of the cub so you end up with one quarter of the cube (we will use the mirror modifier to get the deleted part back). Inset the top and bottom part, delete the face of the inset. fill the hole you have in the cube. Add two loop cut so you have more geometry to work with. Add a circle, use the circle as a guide to move the geometry in order to get a quarter of a circle. move some vertices to have an equal thickness along the rim. add some loop cut to help define the edges (for the subdivision modifier). You can use the vertices on the straight parts of the hole to add some curvature by moving them (see picture 2)

Here is the step by step:[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool, except... OP's shape has 3 holes, not 4. So it needs to be a third of a shape, not a quarter.